# Finding a power series solution for a given differential equation and identifying the function represented by the power series.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion, solution-verification

> Find a power series for the solution of the differential equation
>   $y'(t)-2y(t)=0 ,\ y(0)=5$, and then identify the function represented
>   by the power series.

(I use the following information in order to discover a pattern of the DE).

$y(0)=5 ,\ y'(0)=2y(0)=10 ,\ y''(0)=2y'(0)=20 ,\ y'''(0)=2y''(0)=40 \implies y^{(n)}(0)=5\cdot2^n$
So, $\textbf{ANSWER: }$ $\displaystyle y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5\cdot2^n t^n}{n!}=5\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(2t\right)^n}{n!}=5e^{2t}$

Is my methodology proper; is my method of discovering $y^{(n)}(0)$ analytical enough? It seems like educated conjecture, at best.

Comment: Yes, looks good.  I guess you could do a formal induction, but it is unlikely that that would be expected. From the DE, it is clear that the $(n+1)$-th derivative is $2$ times the $n$-th derivative, so I would not call your calculation of the $n$-th derivative at $0$ a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your method is correct. Basically, to find a power series solution, we would assume the existence of $\{a_n\}$, such that $y(x) = \sum a_n x^n$. The next thing to do would be finding a recurrent form of $a_n$, which leads to finding a closed form of it (in case it exists).

What you have done is that throughout your method, you found the expression of $y^{(n)}(x)$, $n=1,2,...$ But, we know that $a_n = \frac{y^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, $\forall$ $n$. So we also found $\{a_n\}$.